# Sorting is not working on category page

Tags: magento2.3, category-products, sorting

We have dropdown, which have an option to sort the products by position, name, etc., but its not working.

[image]

Could anyone please help me?

Comment: check if you have a custom or third party extension that overrides sorting functionality.